# Infix to postfix with real numbers

Tags: java

I'm trying to do an app that allows translate an infix to postfix express. I can do it for only one digit but when I do it for the whole real number, it shows an error!

```
public String doTrans() {
    for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
        char ch = input.charAt(j);
        theStack.displayStack("For " + ch + " ");
        switch (ch) {
        case '+':
        case '-':
            gotOper(ch, 1);
            break;
        case '*':
        case '/':
            gotOper(ch, 2);
            break;
        case '(':
            theStack.push(ch);
            break;
        case ')':
            gotParen(ch);
            break;
        default:
            if (input.charAt(j + 1) != '+' || input.charAt(j + 1) != '-'
                    || input.charAt(j + 1) != '/'
                    || input.charAt(j + 1) != '('
                    || input.charAt(j + 1) != ')')
                number = number + ch;
            else
                output = output + number;
            break;
        }
    }
    while (!theStack.isEmpty()) {
        theStack.displayStack("While ");
        output = output + theStack.pop();
    }
    theStack.displayStack("End ");
    return output;
}
```

And this is the error!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 14
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at InToPost.doTrans(InToPost.java:33)
    at InfixApp.main(InfixApp.java:15)
```

`if (input.charAt(j + 1) != '+' || input.charAt(j + 1) != '-'...`

The whole program is very long, I can't post it here!

LAST EDIT

```
default:
                if (j != input.length() - 1) {
                    if (input.charAt(j + 1) != '+'
                            || input.charAt(j + 1) != '-'
                            || input.charAt(j + 1) != '/'
                            || input.charAt(j + 1) != '('
                            || input.charAt(j + 1) != ')')
                        number = number + ch;
                    else
                        output = output + number;
                } else
                    output = output + number;
                break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop does this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
    ...
```

And later on you do

```
if (input.charAt(j + 1) != '+' || input.charAt(j + 1) != '-'
```

For this to work your loop has to end with `input.length() - 1`, otherwise you get `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` during the last iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
if (input.charAt(j + 1) != '+' || input.charAt(j + 1) != '-'
```

you are checking the next character.  But what if you are already at the end?  This is how you are running off the end of the `String`.  You will need to detect this case (end of string) separately, before you test the next character.

Comment: Is it true for my last EDIT?

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (input.charAt(j + 1) != '+' || input.charAt(j + 1) != '-'
                || input.charAt(j + 1) != '/'
                || input.charAt(j + 1) != '('
                || input.charAt(j + 1) != ')')
            number = number + ch;
        else
            output = output + number;
```

A simple metarule is that || here should be && because of the !=.

Probably all should be:

```
number += ch;
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: It looks like the intention was `if (ch != '+' && ... && ch != ')')`, which already is covered by the switch. In the default case simply appending to the string, or `number = number*10 + ((int)ch - '0')` would be logical. And somewhere `number = ""`.

Comment: About the metarule: some constructs are very likely erroneous. If using ORs with UNEQUALS, two UNEQUALS always yield true. Either a char is unequal to '+' or unequal to '-', giving true.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (input.charAt(j + 1) != '+' || input.charAt(j + 1) != '-'
                    || input.charAt(j + 1) != '/'
                    || input.charAt(j + 1) != '('
                    || input.charAt(j + 1) != ')')
```

Above code looks for next character if it is a operator or not.

And your for loop goes till input.length(), So just make for loop to go one Position less than the END like this :

for(int j = 0; j < input.length()-1; j++) // So that loop code can safely refer to last character.

Comment: Yes, I've changed it. I didn't notice that. Can you see my code above?